# Material UI Grid Version 2 issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In one react component I decided to use new version of material ui grid new version by importing the component from this address import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2".
after usign  in my component, the app crashed and I have an error with this title:
**Uncaught TypeError: styled_default is not a function at Grid2.js:26**

I decided to change my import location to this address import { Grid } from "@mui/material"
and use the stable version of Grid but the app still is cracked and I have the above error.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I realized that there are two different problems.
It's important that I mention I'm using vite as my package manager and in fact I'll use my app after vite compiles it.
But the first issue is about Grid V2 of material ui, and I said my app will crach if I import it in any component of my app:
***import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2"***
and I will have an error:
**Uncaught TypeError: styled_default is not a function at Grid2.js:26**
but the second problem (a little bit strange) is that when I remove the import line the error will remind and the app is crashed still.

**For the second problem I realized that if I use the 'vite clean' command the problem will solve and I can continue without using GridV2. By the way, I added a script like this to the package.json:
"clean":"vite clean" and in the terminal by calling yarn clean the second problem is solved. **

Comment: When you'd run vite clean, did you get the following: `(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
` If so, what did you end up doing?

Comment: Just curious, but did you find a solution to your first problem? Semi confusing if you did or didn't.

Comment: It works for me. The issue solved successfully. Thank you.